# Are nadis mentioned in yoga physical?

Tags: yoga

In yoga, it has been mentioned that there are 72000 nadis in human body.

Are they physical or non-physcal?

Answer (score 2):

The nadis in yoga and tantra shastra are non-physical/subtle. See [here](http://dlshq.org/download/kundalini.htm#_VPID_32) for a detailed reference.The nadis are the intersection point of vital forces in the spiritual/astral body. As such, they cannot be seen to the naked eye.

As a side, even some ayurvedic physicians and astrologers use the term nadis synonymously to the pulse and nerval plexuses. These are physical objects.